# PyCharm - unbound local errors are not being marked

Tags: pycharm

I must've clicked "*ignore errors like this*", because now unbound local variables that are referenced before assignment aren't marked as such; I would expect a red squiggly line below the variable `idontexist`:

[image]

But, in the settings I've ticked and applied the change to state that unbound local variables should notify me.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. In my case it was the inspection for `Unresolved references` I wanted, not `Unbound local variable`.
2. Remove items from `ignore references` under the Options panel (see the picture below) for a given inspection type.

[image]